# Indexing a 3D np array with two 1D np array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3D `np.array` of shape `(i,j,k)`and two 1D `np.array` contain the indexes in the `j`-axis and `k`-axis.

For example

```
idx = np.array([0, 1])
idy = np.array([1, 2])
array = np.arange(0, 18).reshape(2, 3, 3)
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]]])
```

I want to have `array[0,0,1]`, `array[0,1,2]`, `array[1,0,1]` and `array[1,1,2]` which is `np.array([1,5,10,14])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this enough:

```
In [197]: arr[:,idx,idy]
Out[197]: 
array([[ 1,  5],
       [10, 14]])
In [198]: arr[:,idx,idy].ravel()
Out[198]: array([ 1,  5, 10, 14])
```